# After creating iOS Framework/Bundle NSLog does not allow to log variable Values?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I have created iOS framework using http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/ (open URL in MAC as i am getting 404 not found on windows.)

Now I have kept **NSLogs** in my Framework files. When I log simple messages, it will get printed on console. But when I try to print any variable values it will give me **SIGBART** error.

Are there any constraints while making a framework? Does Framework code is treated separately?

**Edit:**

```
NSLog(@"my variable : %@",variableName);
```

Thanks...

Comment: Can you post code for how you're trying to print the variables? Maybe the problem is something simpler, especially if its only variables it has issues with.

Comment: @KarolyS: I have logged messages in simple way only. pls see the code. I only print the variableName value.

Comment: any one doing downvote please mention the reason if you find it so funny...

Comment: Please paste your code with relevant to variableName.

Comment: @charith: I have added this simplest code in my framework and i have encountered Sigbart error. So I just want to know is there any thing which provides restriction in framework??

Answer (score 1):

Actually the type of the variableName is very important. And also I notice that you are missing the @ in the beginning.

```
NSLog(@"my variable : %@",variableName); // note @ in the beginning. assume variableName is an object type.
```

Comment: Yes, it was typo. but in my code @ is included. I have tried with NSArray, NSDictionary and NSString. All this type is not working. You are saying that Type of variable is important so what does that mean??

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and solved it by setting "build active architecture only" to YES